# Find the value of a polynomial expression of the root of another expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $$x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2} = 1,$$ find the value of $$x^{20} + x^{14} - x^4 + x^2 + 3.$$

I tried factorizing the expression but failed to do so. Can anybody help me to crack it.

Comment: Hint: The roots of $x^2+1/x^2=1$ are $\pm ij$ and $\pm ij^2$, with $j=\exp(2i\pi/3)$.

Answer (score 3):

If you multiply by $x^2$ you find $x^4 + 1 = x^2$ i.e. $x^4 = x^2 -1$. This can be used to reduce the degree of the polynomial:
\begin{align}
x^{20} + x^{14} - x^4 + x^2 + 3
&= (x^{18} - x^{16}) + x^{14} - x^4 + x^2 + 3\\
&=(x^{16}-x^{14}) - x^{16} + x^{14} - x^4 + x^2 + 3\\
&= -(x^2 - 1) + x^2 + 3 \\
&= 4
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2} =1$$

$$x^4 - x^2 + 1 =0$$

$$x^2 = \frac{1 \pm\sqrt{1-4}}{2}$$

$$x^2= -\omega$$ and $$x^2=-{\omega}^2$$

where $\omega$ is the cube root of unity.

Putting the value of $x^2$ in the

equation $x^{20} + x^{14} -x^4 +x^2 +3$

we get,
$$= \omega - \omega - (\omega)^2 -\omega +3$$

$$= 3-\omega-(\omega)^2$$

$$=4$$

Note :
$${\omega}^3=1$$

$$( \omega)^{3n+k}=(\omega)^k$$ where$$ k=0,1,2$$

Answer (score 1):

If $x^2-\frac{1}{x^2}=1$ then for $x\neq0$ it follows that $x^4-x^2+1=0$.
Let's do polynomial division of the two polynomials $x^{20}+x^{14}-x^4+x^2+3$ and $x^4-x^2+1$:

\begin{matrix} (x^{20}&+x^{14}&-x^4&+x^2&+3&&&):(x^4-x^2+1) = x^{16} + x^{14} -1\\
~x^{20}&-x^{18}&+x^{16}&\\
&+x^{18}&-x^{16}&+x^{14}&-x^4&+x^2&+3\\
&+x^{18}&-x^{16}&+x^{14}&    &     &    &   & \\
&&&&-x^4&+x^2&-1&    &   & \\
&&&&&&+4
\end{matrix}
the remainder is $+4$.
Or
$$x^{20}+x^{14}-x^4+x^2+3 = (x^4-x^2+1)(x^{16} + x^{14} -1)+4.$$
If $x^4-x^2+1=0$ then $x^{20}+x^{14}-x^4+x^2+3 = 4$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2} = 1$ then $x^4 = x^2 - 1$. Try to use this fact, along with exponent arithmetic, to reduce terms by replacing $x^4$ with the expression involving a lower exponent.